# Display Product image issue in order email magento2

Tags: magento2, product-images, order-email

I am trying to show product image in order emails.

for that i overrided below file to my custom theme to implement it.

```
Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

$_order = $_item->getOrder();
$_store = $_order->getStore();
$_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()- >get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$_baseImageUrl = $_store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';

$productRepository = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$productSku = $block->getSku($_item);
$productObj = $productRepository->get($productSku);
$imageUrl = $_imageHelper->init($productObj, 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('65','65')->getUrl();
```

Then after the line

```
<p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
```

I added my code like below.

```
  <p><img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" alt="Product Image"></p>
```

This is showing always src as unknown.

But the image is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try below code**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productId = 1;
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
    // $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    // $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getImage())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();

    $directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');

    $rootPath = $directory->getPath('media');
    $imageUrl = $rootPath."/catalog/product".$_product->getImage();

    <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" />
```

> **Note :- *The code will work, but it is best practice to not reference the ObjectManager class directly.***